# How to serialize object to application/hal+json in Spring Boot Unit test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, serialization, spring-hateoas

In a Spring Boot project, I am trying to serialize and deserialize related objects using HATEOAS in hal+json format. I'm using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas` to do so and it works great in my controller:

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/{id}", produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE + ";charset=UTF-8")
HttpEntity<Item> getItemById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    Item item = itemRepository.findById(id).get();
    item.add(linkTo(ItemController.class).slash(item.getId()).withSelfRel());
    item.add(linkTo(methodOn(CategoryController.class).getCategoryById(item.getCategory().getId()))
        .withRel("category"));
    return new HttpEntity<>(item);
}
```

With the `Item` class being:

```java
@Entity
public class Item extends RepresentationModel<Item> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "item_id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "category_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Category category;

    private String name;

    // Getters and Setters are present but not entered here in the question
}
```

Calling the GET method will result in something like

```json
{
  "name": "foo"
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/items/1"
    },
    "category": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/categories/2"
    }
  },
  "item_id": 1
}
```

This is just what I want.

The problem occurs now when I'm trying to write a test for the POST method which is intended to be used for creating new `Item`s. This is what my test looks like:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ItemControllerTest{

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Test
    void testCreate() throws Exception {
        Item testItem = new Item("test");
        testItem.add(Link.of("http://localhost:" + port + "/categories/2", "category"));

        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        ObjectWriter ow = objectMapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        String itemSerialized = ow.writeValueAsString(testItem);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/items/")
            .content(itemSerialized)
            .contentType(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE))
            .andExpect(status().isOK());
    }
}
```

This serialization does not work as needed, as the relations look like this in the `itemSerialized` String:

```
  "links" : [{
    "rel" : "category",
    "href" : "http://localhost:61524/categories/2"
  }]
```

(What would be correct is `_links` with the underscore and a `category` relation structure like given above.)

As I understood, the cause of this is, that the `objectMapper` I use is not aware of the need to serialize to json+hal format. (Which correctly happens by default/magic in the Controller when it returns the `Item` from `getItemById`.) Now, what would be the proper way to ensure, that the correct serialization happens in the test as well?

I have read about using `objectMapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());`, which seems reasonable to me. But when I use it, an exception occurs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalLinkListSerializer': 
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalLinkListSerializer]: 
No default constructor found
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTR, I found a solution after searching and trying a lot. Mainly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44521382/4970679) answer led me the right way. The key is not only to call `objectMapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());`, but also to supply a `HandlerInstantiator`:

My code from above would then be amended like this, the crucial line marked with `//!!`.

```java
@Autowired 
private LinkRelationProvider linkRelationProvider;

@Autowired 
private MessageResolver messageResolver

// ...

    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    objectMapper.setHandlerInstantiator(new Jackson2HalModule.HalHandlerInstantiator(
        linkRelationProvider, CurieProvider.NONE, messageResolver)); //!!
    ObjectWriter ow = objectMapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    String itemSerialized = ow.writeValueAsString(testItem);

// ...
```

This way, no error occurs and the result looks like I want it to. Anyway, I don't know if this is the best possible solution or why Spring Hateoas doesn't initialize things correctly at test time as it does at normal runtime.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you must run your test together with the spring context so that the framework performs all the steps that must be done internally to return a correct HATEOAS response.

it is also better to use TestRestTemplate as it is a spring solution together with jayway and AssertJ libs. This will make testing easier, even if you are doing TDD

Below I leave an example taken from [Spring Academy](https://spring.academy/)

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class CashCardApplicationTests {
@Autowired
TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

@Test
void shouldReturnACashCardWhenDataIsSaved() {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("/cashcards/99", String.class);
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);

    DocumentContext documentContext = JsonPath.parse(response.getBody());
    Number id = documentContext.read("$.id");
    assertThat(id).isEqualTo(99);

    Double amount = documentContext.read("$.amount");
    assertThat(amount).isEqualTo(123.45);
}
}
```

with a structure similar to this you can perform all assertions and tests with ease

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have been using the Spring context via `@SpringBootTest` already in the way you described (updated my question now to include that part), so this does not solve the problem. Concerning TestRestTemplate, I think, this might be useful when testing the results of a GET request e. g. (indeed, I prefer Traverson here though), but my problem deals with the serialization of the object to be POSTed.